# Batch files and MySQL: pass a block of commands instead of another .bat file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I see that I can [pass a batch file to mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html) in order to run a sequence of commands.  But can I put those commands in the same batch file as the one that initiates the mysql app?

I.e. can I pass a block of batch commands to mysql instead of passing a batch file, so that it might look something like this:

```
mysql < [list of commands, not a .bat filename]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pipe commands into MySQL if you don't want/have them in a file:

```
echo " ...some SQL... " | mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

The term "Batch file" in the mySQL manual doesn't refer to DOS .BAT files, but to a file with many mySQL commands.

```
 mysql < list.sql
```

will do exactly what you need.

Comment: You are right of course.  But it still leaves me without help toward my question.

Comment: @Jellicle ahh, I understand now. @wonk0's solution should work for that